# What's the most efficient way to implement multiple controls for multiple media players?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, html5-audio

Let's say I have a web page with 3 `<audio>` elements, each with a different `href=""`, and I want users to be able to play (and pause, and control) more than one of these  elements at the same time.

The `controls` attribute is not present, because I've created a `<button>` element for pause/play, and an `<input type="range>` element for the volume slider. These are connected to the `<audio>` element through JavaScript:

```
<div class="control">

    <audio class="player" src="audio/Light rain inside.opus" loop></audio>
    <div class="arrow-select"></div>
    <div class="control-flex">
        <button type="button" class="pause-play">
            <i id="btn-icon" class="fa-solid fa-play"></i>
        </button> 
        <input class="volume slider" type="range">
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var playing = false;

$(".pause-play").on("click", function() {
     if (playing == false) {
        $(".player").get(0).play();
        $("#btn-icon").removeClass("fa-play");
        $("#btn-icon").addClass("fa-pause");
        playing = true;
    } else {
        $(".player").get(0).pause();
        $("#btn-icon").removeClass("fa-pause");
        $("#btn-icon").addClass("fa-play");
        playing = false;
    }
})

$(".volume").on("input",function(e) {
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    const vol = value / 100;
    $(".player").prop("volume", vol);
});

</script>
```

This applies to a single `.player`, and the most obvious way to make it for other 2 players, is to make 2 more identical `<audio>` elements, add a "2" to all the classes, copy-paste the JavaScript for pause/play and volume, and replace the selectors in there with the corresponding numbers.

However, there must be an extremely more efficient of doing this. I know for the HTML I can make a PHP loop and add a "1", "2", "3"... to the classes of each `<audio>` instance, but I can't work out the JS/JQuery with my knowledge of its syntax (extremely low). Any cool ideas?

**Solution:**

I used a PHP for loop to generate multiple `<audio>` elements with corresponding numbers at the end of their IDs, and then used onclick and oninput events for the interface buttons:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++) { ?>

    <div class="<?php echo "control" . $i ?>">

        <audio 
            id="<?php echo "audio" . $i ?>"
            class="<?php echo "player" . $i ?>" 
            src="<?php echo 'audio/' . $sounds[$i] . '.opus' ?>" 
            loop>
        </audio>
        <div class="arrow-select"></div>
        <div class="audio-display"></div>
        <div class="control-flex">
            <button 
                onclick="pausePlay(
                    '<?php echo 'audio' . $i ?>', 
                    '<?php echo 'btn-icon' . $i ?>'
                )" 
                type="button" 
                class="<?php echo "pause-play" . $i ?>">
                    <i id="<?php echo "btn-icon" . $i ?>" 
                    class="fa-solid fa-play"></i>
            </button> 
            <input oninput="changeVolume(
                '<?php echo 'audio' . $i ?>', 
                this.value
            )" 
                class="<?php echo "volume" . $i ?> slider" 
                id="<?php echo "volume" . $i ?>" 
                type="range"
            >
        </div>

    </div>

<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeVolume(audioId, slider) {
    audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
    const vol = slider / 100;
    $(audio).prop("volume", vol);
}

function pausePlay(audioId, iconId) {

    var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
    var icon = document.getElementById(iconId); 

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        $(icon).removeClass("fa-play");
        $(icon).addClass("fa-pause");
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        $(icon).removeClass("fa-pause");
        $(icon).addClass("fa-play");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm reviewing questions from new users: some feedback: this is a good question. Can you also provide an outline of the HTML code?  I can guess what you mean, but having a pared down example of the HTML you're working with helps.